# Где лучше хранить временную статистику, MySQL или Json?

Tags: python, mysql, json

Есть игровой сервер (cs:go).
В течении раунда нужно записывать заработанные очки игроков (за разные действия, по типу убийства противника), затем, в конце каждого раунда с этими очками производится определённая операция, к примеру, если команда проиграла раунд - очки делятся на 2. После, эти очки отправляются в БД.

Вот и назрел такой вопрос, если в базе данных будет 10.000 игроков, наверное для хранения временной статистики это не самый лучший вариант? Пришла мысль использовать Json, куда будут записываться игроки и заработанные ими очки, затем в конце раунда эти очки будут забираться из файла и отправляться в БД, а сам файл - очищаться. В общем в файле будет примерно 30 строк.

Как мне поступить, MySQL или JSON? (Пишу на Python, если это важно.)

Comment: Если временной — зачем её вообще хранить где-то кроме оперативной памяти?

Comment: @andreymal Большое спасибо, мне даже в голову как-то не пришло :D